# Unity: .car file format?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have file (not mine) with extension `.car`. As I understand, it is resource/model, that can be used in Unity Engine. Thats the beginning of file:

```
UnityFS\0\0\0\0\u{06}5.x.x\05.3.5f1\0\0\0\0\0\0\u{19}O—\0\0\0B\0\0\0[\0\0\0C\u{1E}\0\u{01}\0±\u{01}\0m\u{03}x\0\u{19}O\'\0A\u{0E}\0\u{08}\u{01}\0\0\u{1A}\0ð\u{19}\0\0\u{04}CAB-67e90ee36cdeede366978c2174a31d41\0]\0\0\u{08}\0\0\0aJ„Ð Ñ\u{10}Ô\u{0F}uÁÇç=çÎÀŸÀ˜×\u{02}£\u{7F}ÓOÇ\u{12}‹€\u{0F}\u{1E}\u{10}ª\n;\\Vÿ|Íü\u{17} N}´\u{1B}•QréýnI\n3pÍ¸e¢~\u{0B}(õ×<o¨Éw{\u{10}\u{0C}ÎJgx\u{04}ºa–q\n\u{1E}\r\u{0B}\u{01}ß¾Ÿ\u{02}%Ðƒ3gc‚{Õ*³éÓÓßH[ùë\u{0F}b!yÈ\u{10}ðqîà},²}ñ\u{0B}éª4¤Dš”\'ˆÐ×ÿ‚†nœ ”„}dû›ö×Pj=\u{06}æ®e}Hél\"F•›è¾’ÄxPb¯\"³=\u{1A}à!\u{1A}|ß>Ð\u{10}ªv\u{14}Ò]²\u{13}ª K\t\u{0C}\u{05}rè%G\u{10}}‡û\u{12}ýù\u{14}ú&p¨l‹\u{1F}kÔ%á8ß@;\u{02}e[üqL±¬²Çª:Lx 1º3+fZR˜…ˆ¯[\u{01}npg1\u{03}
```

I've tried to add it to Unity Editor, but there I can't do anything with this file.

Can you please explain what the file it is and how can I use It (if it is possible) ?

[image: carfile]

Answer (score 0):

CAR stands for Component Application Resource. The CAR files contain information about the assets that are available for a software application being run on the Brew Mobile Platform. This platform is used to operate applications on a variety of mobile phones. The CAR files are compiled into a binary BAR file. This file is automatically loaded when the application is run.

The .car file extension is also used for AtHome Assistant files, Biosym chemical modeler input files, NeoBook Cartoon image format files, CAR Archive compressed archive files, CardMaker card files, Carnivores Ice Age resource files, Design-Your-CD data files and Railroad Tycoon 3 car properties files.

As for using it, I'm not sure you would probably have to dig deep into the brew sdk:

https://developer.brewmp.com/content/about-brew-mp-sdk